# Ruby on Rails: How may create a quoted string to a request header?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing from scratch a Twitter client and one of the requisites is **not** using Twitter gems, so I must create my own requests.

Twitter API  documentation says [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request) that I must have a Authorization header like this:

```
Authorization:
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog",
oauth_nonce="kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg",
oauth_signature="tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_timestamp="1318622958",
oauth_token="370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb",
oauth_version="1.0"
```

As you may see I must have something like `oauth_consumer_key="xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog"` with the second part in quotes. I tried using %Q like in

```
["oauth_consumer_key",%Q( Figaro.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN )].join('=')
```

assuming %Q would return a quoted string. but when I inspect the value, all I get is

```
oauth_consumer_key=xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog
```

which, obviously, is different from the required result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. My solution:**

```
'oauth_consumer_key="#{Figaro.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN}"'
```

**2. Why:**

`%Q()` basically replaces the variable with double quotes `""`, it is literally the same as if you wrote `"Figaro.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"`

In fact, to display the **content** of a variable, you have to use [interpolation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation)
   instead of the name itself, using `"#{var}"`.

You can also use `%Q` directly with interpolation using `%Q{var}` (note `{}` instead of `()`).

Your problem is elsewhere: with the [join()](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) method. It's getting rid of double quotes. In that case doing `["var", var].join('=')` and `["var", %Q{var}].join('=')` ends doing exactly the same thing but more complicated.

**@Artem Ignatiev's solution should works**. But if you need to be more readable, you don't even need to join, imho, it makes sense only when you are using more than two variables.

For instance, I will use something like `'oauth_consumer_key="#{var}"'` mixing single and double quote to make sure it causes no confusions.

If you **do** need to use `%Q()` and `join`, you can still use `["oauth_consumer_key", %Q("#{Figaro.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN})].join('=')`.

- Note that because of the `join` you can use single quote interpolation `%q` or double quote interpolation `%Q` without affecting the ends results:

*e.g*

```
['oauth_consumer_key', %q("#{var}")].join('=') == ["oauth_consumer_key", %Q("#{var}")].join('=')
```

Answer (score 1):

`%Q(x)` is basically the same as "x".

To achieve the desired result you have to manually introduce quotes into `%Q` expression, like this: `%Q("#{Figaro.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN}")`

Comment: I am getting the same thing with this. Isn't there a `quoted_str` helper or something?

Comment: I believe there is none because it is very easy to write: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/timon/039d8b57b41dfcc523610f1b9987204e#file-quoted_header-rb)